# Convert DateTime To JSON DateTime

Tags: c#, .net, json, web-services

I have a WebService which return DateTime Field.

I get a result `/Date(1379048144000)/` but

i want just `1379048144000` how can i achieve that.

```
[WebMethod]
public DateTime GetServerDate()
{
    return DateTime.Now;
}
```

by setting Header Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8; i got a result like `/Date(1379048144000)/`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could change your WS to return a long with the value of the DateTime.  The value to return is the number of milliseconds since the Unix Epoch (01/01/1970).  This could be done with an extension method on `DateTime` something like:

```
public static class DateTimeExtensions
{
    ...
    private static readonly DateTime UnixEpoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);

    public static long ToUnixTime(this DateTime dateTime)
    {
        return (dateTime - UnixEpoch).Ticks / TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond;
    }
    ...
}
```

And your web service method might look something like:

```
public long GetMyDate(...)
{
    DateTime dateTime = ...;
    return dateTime.ToUnixTime();
}
```

Comment: Here is how .NET source code has set the epoch time: new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc), which might be more accurate. Ref: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data.Services/System/Data/Services/Serializers/JsonWriter.cs,2ea1b57fdee2095f,references

Answer (score 9):

with [Json.NET](https://json.codeplex.com/) :

```
string date = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(DateTime.Now);
```

Answer (score 5):

in client side you can use this function to show a right date to client(I use it on my projects):

```
function parseJsonDate(jsonDate) {
var offset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * 60000;
var parts = /\/Date\((-?\d+)([+-]\d{2})?(\d{2})?.*/.exec(jsonDate);
if (parts[2] == undefined) parts[2] = 0;
if (parts[3] == undefined) parts[3] = 0;
d = new Date(+parts[1] + offset + parts[2] * 3600000 + parts[3] * 60000);
date = d.getDate() + 1;
date = date < 10 ? "0" + date : date;
mon = d.getMonth() + 1;
mon = mon < 10 ? "0" + mon : mon;
year = d.getFullYear();
return (date + "." + mon + "." + year);
};
```

This function is return right date in format: dd.mm.yyyy, but you can change it if you need. I hope that I help you.

Comment: I believe that you should change: date = d.getDate() + 1;
To: date = d.getDate();

Comment: i was getting date as : "\/Date(1476775277500)\/". This solution worked for me as well , thank you ! , able to convert to proper js date

Answer (score 2):

U can always solve your problem when sending a date in a JSON object to JS by converting the date as follows:

```
var myJSDate = (new Date(parseInt(obj.MyDate.substr(6)))).toJSON();
```

Where obj.Date contains the date you wanna format.

Then u'll get something like this: "2013-10-25T18:04:17.289Z"

U can always check it in Chrome console by writing:

```
(new Date()).toJSON();
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions:

1. client side:

```html
function ToJavaScriptDate(value) {
  var pattern = /Date\(([^)]+)\)/;
  var results = pattern.exec(value);
  var dt = new Date(parseFloat(results[1]));
  return (dt.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + dt.getDate() + "/" + dt.getFullYear();
}
```

It is possible to need alsou to convert into data object
var date = new Date(xxx)

2. Server side:

   ```
   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(your_object)
   ```

Answer (score -1):

Simply write like this to convert your date string in JSON format.

```
date = "{" + date + "}";
```

Answer (score -2):

try regex:

```
var jsonDate = @"/Date(1379048144000)/"; 
var regex = /-?\d+/; 
var jsonDate = re.exec(jsonDate); 
var dateOriginal = new Date(parseInt(m[0]));
```

Comment: i am returning DateTime and that return as `/Date(1379048144000)/` i have no '/Date(1379048144000)/' within that c# code it is only respons whilwe calling by json post

Comment: then where u want to parse? javascript? server side?

Comment: i want to return only `1379048144000` by serverside c# .