# How to get json data in return using mvc and entity framework

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, controller

getting error at orderby g.datetime 
**error**

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1061  'IGrouping' does not contain a definition for 'datetime' and no extension method 'datetime' accepting a first argument of type 'IGrouping' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   waterleveltesting   c:\users\kernel\documents\visual studio 2015\watertower\waterleveltesting\waterleveltesting\Controllers\waterController.cs  22  Active

```
id  waterlevel     datetime                 towerid
1   25             2016-09-21 01:10:00.000  1
2   33             2016-09-21 01:11:00.000  2

op- [{"towerid":"1","waterlevel":25,"datetime":"Nov 09, 2016 07:02:25PM"},{"towerid":"33","waterlevel":22,"datetime":"Nov 09, 2016 07:02:25PM"}]
```

**My code:**

```
     public ActionResult Getwaterlevel()
    {
        using (waterlevel_Entities DB = new waterlevel_Entities())
        {
            var wt = from w in DB.watertowerlevels
                     group w by w.towerid into g
                     orderby g.datetime
                     select new
                     {
                         towerid = g.Key,
                         waterlevel = g.FirstOrDefault().waterlevel,
                         datetime = g.FirstOrDefault().datetime.ToString("MMM yyy")
                     };


            return Json(wt.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);


        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get first records of each group in LINQ. You could try to use this one:
Also notice we have to treat `C# Date` a bit special here:

```
        var wt = from w in DB.watertowerlevels
                 group w by w.towerid into g
                 orderby g.datetime
                 select new { towerid = g.Key, waterlevel = g.FirstOrDefault().waterlevel,
                 datetime = g.FirstOrDefault().datetime.ToString("MMM yyyy")};


 return  Json(wt.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: what is p here?

Comment: json data coming like this- [{"towerid":1,"waterlevel":25,"datetime":"\/Date(1474400400000)\/"},{"towerid":2,"waterlevel":33,"datetime":"\/Date(1474400460000)\/"}]

Comment: why date is coming like that \/Date(14744004000‌​00)\/

Comment: I used to try and error when learning :)
could you please try
`select new { towerid = g.Key, wol = g.ToList()};`
let see what it return

Comment: [{"towerid":1,"wol":[{"id":1,"waterlevel":25,"datetime":"\/Date(1474400400000)\/","towerid":1}]},{"towerid":2,"wol":[{"id":2,"waterlevel":33,"datetime":"\/Date(1474400460000)\/","towerid":2}]}]

Comment: please check this one http://stackoverflow.com/a/18821102/5929494
or try this one
`datetime = g.FirstOrDefault().datetime.ToString("MMM yyyy")`