# C# convert datetime to WCF datetime format

Tags: c#, json, wcf, json.net

I parse c# object that has DateTime property with JsonNet and then I post it to the server. But it returns that the date format is wrong. It request to be with format like this:

```
"/Date(1327572000000-1000)/"
```

How can I convert c# DateTime to this format?

Comment: Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1016908)

Comment: @Arman C# and Javascript are different

Comment: Oops, I copied the wrong link, apologies for that. I meant this one [https://stackoverflow.com/a/18821102](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18821102).

Comment: @Arman now that helps a lot. thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you asked how to serialize with this format using JSON.NET:

```
// Set the DateFormatHandling wherever you are configuring JSON.Net.
// This is usually globally configured per application.
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.MicrosoftDateFormat
};

// When you serialize, DateTime and DateTimeOffset values will be in this format.
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(yourDateTimeValue, settings);
```

However, I highly recommend you do NOT use this format unless you absolutely have to, usually for purposes of compatibility with old code.  The ISO-8601 format is preferred (de facto) format for dates and times in JSON.

See also:  [On the nightmare that is JSON Dates](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/OnTheNightmareThatIsJSONDatesPlusJSONNETAndASPNETWebAPI.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

This is how WCF essentially serializes DateTime values (note that non-UTC values include information about current time zone)

```
public static string MsJson(DateTime value)
{
    long unixEpochTicks = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc).Ticks;
    long ticks = (value.ToUniversalTime().Ticks - unixEpochTicks) / 10000;

    if (value.Kind == DateTimeKind.Utc)
    {
        return String.Format("/Date({0})/", ticks);
    }
    else
    {
        TimeSpan ts = TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.GetUtcOffset(value.ToLocalTime());
        string sign = ts.Ticks < 0 ? "-" : "+";
        int hours = Math.Abs(ts.Hours);
        string hs = (hours < 10) 
            ? "0" + hours 
            : hours.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        int minutes = Math.Abs(ts.Minutes);
        string ms = (minutes < 10) 
            ? "0" + minutes 
            : minutes.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        return string.Format("/Date({0}{1}{2}{3})/", ticks, sign, hs, ms);
    }
}
```